# 1 click open more than 1 link html

Tags: php, xhtml

I made a page which I put all links next to each other. Every link opens different website. I have to click one by one to them in order to open them and there are 20 links so it takes while everytime. Is there anybody knows how can I make it so when I click only 1 link it opens all of them ?

Comment: Do you want to automate clicking links for personal use, or do you want a client-side script that runs on (and is provided by) your site? JavaScript seems the logical choice here.

Comment: You can use iMacros for Firefox for such task. But if you want to do that on your website.. just don't do it

Comment: Only thing I want is that, I want to go to page that I made. Be able to open 10 windows by 1 click so I don`t have to click one by one doesn`t matter which language

Comment: It`s not on my website. I`m a computer technician. There are around 5-6 programs that I install to the computer every time after I format them. Every time I have to click all of them one by one to open and install them. Each of them opens their website. Exaxple; Ashampoo, Winrar, K-Lite Codec......

Comment: So save the installers to a USB key and install from there instead of downloading them fresh every time … or (if you're in a corporate environment with a site license) set up a windows image that has them pre-installed and use that.

Comment: What`s gonna happen when those programs releases updated versions. Out of Date !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript, but popup blockers and what not are going to get in the way.

You're looking for [`window.open()`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm).

If it were me, I'd just build an all-in-one installer with NSIS, or at least zip the installers into one ZIP file to distribute.

Comment: What`s gonna happen when those programs releases updated versions ? Out of date !

Comment: @Extelliqent, it isn't difficult to drop the new versions over the old and one-click rebuild.

Comment: There are 12 programs that I install everytime. First of all it is difficult to know when they release new version. Second I don`t want to spend 5 mins figuring it out. Thank you for your advice tho.